# Deletando uma Session automaticamente

Tags: php

Oq eu estou pensando em fazer é "sair" com um `session_destroy()` quando o mesmo usuário fizer login em algum outro lugar. 
Existe uma maneira de fazer isso ?

Comment: O que quis dizer com o mesmo usuário fazer login em outro lugar?

Comment: @WendelRodrigues em um outro navegador por exemplo

Comment: Acho que a SESSION é vinculada ao navegador. Então, como vc faria pra matar uma de outro navegador?

Comment: @DvD exatamente gostaria de saber a respeito disso, gostaria de tornar meu site mais seguro, efetuando a seguinte ação de deslogar da conta caso seja efetuado em outro lugar, eu vi uma pergunta parecida no stack em ingles e fiquei curioso em implementar isso, mas as explicações estavam um tanto quanto dificil de entender

Comment: Acho que isso não tem como. O que vc teria quer fazer era um token de acesso no servidor (via banco ou arquivo), e quando o cara logar em outrolugar, verificar se esse token está ativo e matar ele.

Comment: @DvD vou dar uma olhada a respeito, obrigado

Comment: Creio que vc vai ter que criar um campo em uma tabela no banco de dados e vai ter que trabalhar com cookie. Dai vc armazena no cookie alguma hash e armazena ela no banco também. Dai vc verifica se a hash do cookie e do banco são iguais, se for diferente vc faz logoff. Pra isso cada vez que logar vc tem que gerar uma hash e armazenar no banco e no cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ficou confuso sua pergunta, mas vou tentar desmembrar algumas possibilidades que consegui perceber com sua pergunta.

**Situação Um / Usuário Logado**

- O usuário está logado e neste momento temos uma session para este usuário.
- O usuário tentou logar novamente em outro browser o sistema irá criar outra session para este mesmo usuário.
- O sistema neste cenário está permitindo o usuário logar diversas vezes sem restrição.

**Situação dois / Validando Session**

- O usuário está logado e neste momento temos uma session para este usuário.
- O usuário tentou logar em outro browser você fez uma função para checar se a session existe para este usuário e caso esteja logado não permitir que ele logue novamente.

**Situação três / Destroy Session**

- O usuário está logado e neste momento temos uma session para este usuário.
- Quero fechar a session em PHP podemos usar session_destroy(), esta função irá remover toda a session deste usuário, todas as variáveis criadas serão destruídas ou seja destrói todos os dados associados com a sessão atual, ela não apaga nenhuma das variáveis globais associadas à sessão atual, nem apaga o cookie de sessão, para usar as variáveis de sessão novamente, session_start() deve ser chamada.

*Importante* salientar que não é necessário chamar session_destroy(), ao invés de destruir os dados da sessão, limpe o array $_SESSION e pronto.

*Outro ponto importante* é que se $_SESSION (ou $HTTP_SESSION_VARS para PHP 4.0.6 ou inferior) for usada, use unset() para desregistrar a variável da sessão, isto é, unset($_SESSION['varname']);.

**Cuidado**

Não elimine completamente $_SESSION com unset($_SESSION) já que isto desabilitará o registro de variáveis de sessão através da super global $_SESSION.

Você também pode usar session_unset(void) que libera todas as variáveis de sessão registradas.

**Session em Arquivo ou em Redis**

Existe a possibilidade de usar session em arquivo que já é a configuração padrão atualmente, ou em banco de dados como o Redis, o comportamento é transparente em ambos os casos.

**Gerenciando sessions de usuários logados**

Em aplicações que precisamos gerenciar os ambientes e não permitir usuários logados múltiplas vezes, horários de utilização do sistema e proibir o acesso, necessidade de checar se o usuário está online ou derrubar o sistema.

Neste cenário citado acima de controles de acesso, você poderá implementar lendo o arquivo da session seja ele em arquivo ou em banco.

Vou mostrar como fazer isto lendo um arquivo por exemplo:

Temos a função session_decode ela decodifica os dado de sessão serializados fornecidos em $data e preenche a super global $_SESSION com o resultado.

O código ficaria assim:

```
$pathFile = "/tmp/sess_vvk5ff5u1jjabatog0353pce4lc3mpc9";
$conteudo = file_get_contents($pathFile);
session_decode($conteudo);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

A desvantagem deste recurso é que ele coloca tudo em $_SESSION, e não terá um resultado que gostaria.

A outra forma e mais segura é decodificar o arquivo ele possui um padrão e usando unserialize você irá conseguir criar um vetor com todas as variáveis que está na session.

O método ou função para fazer a decodificação do arquivo de sessão seria assim:

```
while ($offset < strlen($conteudo_session)) {
if (!strstr(substr($conteudo_session, $offset), "|")) {
  throw new Exception("invalido o seu conteudo " . substr($conteudo_session, $offset));
    }
    $pos = strpos($conteudo_session, "|", $offset);
    $num = $pos - $offset;
    $varname = substr($conteudo_session, $offset, $num);
    $offset += $num + 1;
    $data = unserialize(substr($conteudo_session, $offset));
    $return_data[$varname] = $data;
    $offset += strlen(serialize($data));

}

return $return_data;
```

Desta forma consegue saber se usuário está online, consegue derrubar um usuário mesmo você conectado com outro usuário, consegue fazer um script para checar se o usuário pode está logado naquele momento e diversas outras possibilidades.

Bem espero ter ajudado, apesar de não ficar bem claro a pergunta deixei algumas observações sobre session_destroy que podem ser úteis.

Comment: Muito obrigado era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando, quando o usuario loga no meu site eu salvo o `session_id` e queria saber se tinha como deslogar, com a sua explicação consegui ver como vou poder implementar no caso era a "situação 3" que você escreveu

Comment: Excelente, imaginei .... sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tornar as sessões previsíveis, para você. Isso tem um risco envolvido, mas assim você conseguiria destruir a sessão anterior, sabendo o estado atual.

---

Na teoria a ideia a minha ideia é simples, no banco de dados você teria:

```
Id | Usuario | ... | Semente     | Estado
 1 | Alice   | ... | (Aleatório) | 1
 2 | Bob     | ... | (Aleatório) | 5
```

Também teria uma chave fixa, preferencialmente fora do código, como numa variável de ambiente, mas não no mesmo local/servidor do banco de dados. Mas, para facilitar o entendimento, algo como:

```
$ChavePrivada = '...'; // Chave de 512 bits aleatória.
```

---

Então você teria que fazer:

```
HMAC(HMAC( {ESTADO} , {SEMENTE} ), {CHAVE PRIVADA DA APLICAÇÃO})
```

Dessa forma, por exemplo, no caso da Alice:

```
HMAC(HMAC('0', 'ABCDE... Aleatório'), 'ASDFG... Aleatório'))
```

Quando Alice efetuar um novo login, você fará:

```
HMAC(HMAC('1', 'ABCDE... Aleatório'), 'ASDFG... Aleatório'))
//...
HMAC(HMAC('2', 'ABCDE... Aleatório'), 'ASDFG... Aleatório'))
//...
HMAC(HMAC('3', 'ABCDE... Aleatório'), 'ASDFG... Aleatório'))
```

Como você percebeu, isso será sequencial. Isso indica que a sessão sempre irá incrementar, o último acesso do usuário está no nosso "Estado", por isso para destruir as sessões anteriores basta fazer `Estado -1` e iremos obter o identificador da sessão anterior.

O segundo HMAC, com uma chave da aplicação, tem o proposito de impedir que alguém consiga prever/recuperar mesmo se tiver acesso a semente de outros usuários.

---

Na prática:

```
const ChavePrivada = '...'; // Define uma chave SEGURA de 512 bits.
```

```
function calcularSessao(string $semente, int $estado) : string {
    return hash_hmac('sha512',
             hash_hmac('sha512', $estado, $semente, true), 
           ChavePrivada);
}
```

```
function encerrarSessoesRecentes(string $semente, int $estado) {
   for($i = ($estado - 6); $i < $estado; $estado++){
      unlink('/tmp/sess_' . calcularSessao($semente, $i));
   }
}
```

Depois para definir a sessão do usuário:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($link);
mysqli_autocommit($link, false);
mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT ..., Semente, Estado FROM ... WHERE ... FOR UPDATE');

//...
if($SenhaCorreta){

    encerrarSessoesRecentes($Semente, $Estado);

    mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE ... SET Estado = Estado + 1 WHERE ...');
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($link) !== 1){
        mysqli_rollback($link);
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_commit($link);

    session_id(calcularSessao($Semente, $Estado));
    session_start();

    //...
}
```

> Irei melhorar e testar o exemplo depois, e atualizo a resposta, mas acredito que dê para entender.

---

> /!\ Cuidado:

Isso não foi desenvolvido por nenhum profissional de segurança. Ele pode ter outros problemas que não fui capaz de identificar, assim existindo outros ataques que serão bem sucedidos. **Se descobrir algum por favor comente**.